# Принтер не печатает штрих-код

Tags: c++, печать, принтер

Здравствуйте. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться почему принтер не хочет печатать штрих код из моей программы.
Для генерации штрих кода я использую библиотеку скачанную отсюда http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13608/A-C-Barcode-Library

Сразу скажу, что принтер рабочий, пробовал печатать на нем текст и картинку из файла, с помощью другой программы.

Вот исходный код, в котором вызывается генерация штрих кода и печать.
// Barcode2Image.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Winspool.h>
#include <CommDlg.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <atlstr.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include "Barcode.h"

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TCHAR   szDriver[16] = _T("WINSPOOL");
    HDC     hdcPrint = NULL;
    BOOL    bReturn = FALSE;
    TCHAR   szPrinter[256];
    DWORD   cchBuffer = 255;
    HANDLE  hPrinter = NULL;
    BYTE    pdBuffer[16384];
    DWORD   cbBuf = sizeof (pdBuffer);
    DWORD   cbNeeded = 0;
    PRINTER_INFO_2  *pPrinterData;
    pPrinterData = (PRINTER_INFO_2 *)&pdBuffer[0];

    bReturn = GetDefaultPrinter(szPrinter, &cchBuffer);

    if (bReturn)
        bReturn = OpenPrinter(szPrinter, &hPrinter,NULL);

    if (bReturn) {
        bReturn =  GetPrinter(hPrinter, 2, &pdBuffer[0], cbBuf, &cbNeeded);
        ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
    }

    if (bReturn)
       hdcPrint = CreateDC(szDriver, szPrinter, pPrinterData->pPortName, NULL); 

    if(hdcPrint) {
        COLORREF color = RGB(0,0,0);
        COLORREF colorSpace = RGB(255,255,255);
        const char* code = "12345";
        Barcode128* BarcodeGen = new Barcode128();
        BarcodeGen->Encode128A(code);
        BarcodeGen->Draw128(hdcPrint, 10, 10, 100, color, colorSpace, 2);

        cout << "Printed" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "HDCPrint error" << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

И вот сама скачанная библиотека - заголовочный файл в котором я удалил лишние классы, например удалил Code39 и т.д., Оставил только базовый класс, и класс для Code128, потому что мне нужна генерация именно этого штрих кода.

```
#ifndef Barcode_h_djdfkjdjkfgjgjghdhdhdgdgfgfgfgeue
#define Barcode_h_djdfkjdjkfgjgjghdhdhdgdgfgfgfgeue


class Barcode39;
class Barcode93;
class BarcodeIof5;
class Barcode128;

const int ga2_Code128[2][207]=
{
    {
        64,  65,  66,  67,  68,  69,  70,  71,  72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,  78,  79,
        80,  81,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,  88,  89,  90,  91,  92,  93,  94,  95,
        0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,  13,  14,  15,
        16,  17,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24,  25,  26,  27,  28,  29,  30,  31,
        32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,  39,  40,  41,  42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47,
        48,  49,  50,  51,  52,  53,  54,  55,  56,  57,  58,  59,  60,  61,  62,  63,
        -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,
        -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,
        -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,
        -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,
        -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,
        -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,
        -1,  -1,  -1,  95,  96,  97,  98,  99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106,
    },
    {
        -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,
        -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,
        0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,  13,  14,  15,
        16,  17,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24,  25,  26,  27,  28,  29,  30,  31,
        32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,  39,  40,  41,  42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47,
        48,  49,  50,  51,  52,  53,  54,  55,  56,  57,  58,  59,  60,  61,  62,  63,
        64,  65,  66,  67,  68,  69,  70,  71,  72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,  78,  79,
        80,  81,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,  88,  89,  90,  91,  92,  93,  94,  -1,
        -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,
        -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,
        -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,
        -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,
        -1,  -1,  -1,  95,  96,  97,  98,  99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106,
    },
};


class BarcodeBase
{
public:
    BarcodeBase()
    {
        Clear();
        i_Ratio=3;
    }

    void operator=(const BarcodeBase&bc)
    {
        i_LenBuf=bc.i_LenBuf;
        i_Ratio =bc.i_Ratio;
        memcpy(ia_Buf,bc.ia_Buf,sizeof(ia_Buf));
    }

    void Clear()
    {
        memset(ia_Buf,0,sizeof(ia_Buf));
        i_LenBuf=0;
    }

    int GetEncodeLength()   const
    {
        BYTE*pb=(BYTE*)ia_Buf;
        int i,iLen=0;
        for(i=0;i<i_LenBuf;i++)
        {
            //wide is 3
            if(*pb&2)   iLen+=(i_Ratio-1);
            pb++;
        }
        return iLen+i_LenBuf;
    }
    int GetBufferLength()   const
    {
        return i_LenBuf;
    }
    const BYTE&GetAt(int i) const 
    {
        return ia_Buf[i];
    }
    int GetRatio()  const
    {
        return i_Ratio;
    }
    int SetRatio(int iRatio)
    {
        i_Ratio=iRatio;
        if(i_Ratio<=0)  i_Ratio=1;
    }
    void DrawBarcode(HDC hDC,int iX,int iY0,int iY10,int iY11,const COLORREF clrBar,const COLORREF clrSpace,const int iPenW)
    {
        HPEN hPenBar    =::CreatePen(PS_SOLID,iPenW,clrBar);
        HPEN hPenSpace  =::CreatePen(PS_SOLID,iPenW,clrSpace);

        HPEN hPenOld=(HPEN)::SelectObject(hDC,hPenBar);

        BYTE*pb=ia_Buf;
        int i0,iNum0=i_LenBuf;

        BYTE bBar;
        int i1,iNum1;
        int iY;
        for(i0=0;i0<iNum0;i0++)
        {
            bBar    =*pb&0x01;
            iNum1   =(*pb&0x02)?i_Ratio:1;
            iY      =(*pb&0x04)?iY11:iY10;
            for(i1=0;i1<iNum1;i1++)
            {
                if(bBar)    ::SelectObject(hDC,hPenBar);
                else        ::SelectObject(hDC,hPenSpace);

                ::MoveToEx(hDC,iX,iY0,0);
                ::LineTo(hDC,iX,iY);
                iX+=iPenW;
            }
            pb++;
        }

        ::SelectObject(hDC,hPenOld);

        ::DeleteObject(hPenBar);
        ::DeleteObject(hPenSpace);
    }
public:
    BYTE    ia_Buf[4096];
protected:

    int     i_LenBuf;

    int     i_Ratio;

    struct IntString
    {
        int ch;
        char*psz;
    };

};

class Barcode128:public BarcodeBase
{
public:
    Barcode128()
    {
    }
    ~Barcode128()
    {
    }

    BOOL Encode128A(const char* pszCode)    {return P_Encode128((char*)pszCode,SUB::SETA);}
    BOOL Encode128B(const char* pszCode)    {return P_Encode128((char*)pszCode,SUB::SETB);}
    BOOL Encode128C(const char* pszCode)    {return P_Encode128((char*)pszCode,SUB::SETC);}

    void Draw128(HDC hDC,int iX,int iY0,int iY1,const COLORREF clrBar,const COLORREF clrSpace,const int iPenW)
    {
        DrawBarcode(hDC,iX,iY0,iY1,iY1,clrBar,clrSpace,iPenW);
    }

private:
    struct SUB
    {
        enum
        {
            SETA=0,
            SETB=1,
            SETC=2,
        };
    };

    BOOL P_Encode128(char*pszCode,const int iSetIn)
    {
        Clear();
        BYTE*pFst=ia_Buf;
        BYTE*pb=pFst;


        if(iSetIn==SUB::SETA)   pb=P_GetBarSpace128(pb,103);
        else
        if(iSetIn==SUB::SETB)   pb=P_GetBarSpace128(pb,104);
        else                    pb=P_GetBarSpace128(pb,105);
        if(pb==0)   return 0;

        const int iCheckDigit=GetCheckDigit(iSetIn,pszCode);
        const int iNum=strlen(pszCode);

        int iChar,iCharNext;
        int iPosition=0;
        int iSet=iSetIn;

        while(iPosition<iNum)
        {
            if(iSet==SUB::SETC)
            {
                if(ga2_Code128[SUB::SETA][pszCode[iPosition]]==101)
                {
                    pb=P_GetBarSpace128(pb,101);
                    iPosition++;
                    iSet=SUB::SETA;
                }
                else 
                if(ga2_Code128[SUB::SETA][pszCode[iPosition]]==100)
                {
                    pb=P_GetBarSpace128(pb,100);
                    iPosition++;
                    iSet=SUB::SETB;
                }
                else if(ga2_Code128[SUB::SETA][pszCode[iPosition]]==102)
                {
                    pb=P_GetBarSpace128(pb,100);
                    iPosition++;
                }
                else
                {
                    char chT=pszCode[iPosition+2];
                    pszCode[iPosition+2]=0;
                    iChar=atoi(&pszCode[iPosition]);
                    pszCode[iPosition+2]=chT;

                    pb=P_GetBarSpace128(pb,iChar);
                    if(pb==0)   return 0;
                    iPosition +=2;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                int iTemp2=pszCode[iPosition];
                if(iTemp2<-1)   iTemp2=iTemp2&255;

                iChar=ga2_Code128[iSet][iTemp2];

                pb=P_GetBarSpace128(pb,iChar);
                if(pb==0)   return 0;
                iPosition++;
                if(iSet==SUB::SETA)
                {
                    if(iChar==100)  iSet=SUB::SETB;
                    else 
                    if(iChar==99)   iSet=SUB::SETC;
                }
                else if(iSet==SUB::SETB)
                {
                    if(iChar==101)  iSet=SUB::SETA;
                    else 
                    if(iChar==99)   iSet=SUB::SETC;
                }
                else 
                if(iChar==98)
                {
                    if(iSet==SUB::SETA)
                        iCharNext=ga2_Code128[SUB::SETB][pszCode[iPosition]];
                    else
                        iCharNext=ga2_Code128[SUB::SETA][pszCode[iPosition]];

                    pb=P_GetBarSpace128(pb,iChar);
                    if(pb==0)   return 0;
                    iPosition++;
                }
            }
        }

        pb=P_GetBarSpace128(pb,iCheckDigit);
        if(pb==0)   return 0;
        pb=P_GetBarSpace128(pb,106);
        i_LenBuf=pb-pFst;

        return 1;
    }

    BYTE*P_GetBarSpace128(BYTE*pb,int iV)
    {
        if(iV<0)    return 0;
        if(iV>106)  return 0;
        IntString infs[]=
        {
            {0,     "bbsbbssbbss"},
            {1,     "bbssbbsbbss"},
            {2,     "bbssbbssbbs"},
            {3,     "bssbssbbsss"},
            {4,     "bssbsssbbss"},
            {5,     "bsssbssbbss"},
            {6,     "bssbbssbsss"},
            {7,     "bssbbsssbss"},
            {8,     "bsssbbssbss"},
            {9,     "bbssbssbsss"},
            {10,    "bbssbsssbss"},
            {11,    "bbsssbssbss"},
            {12,    "bsbbssbbbss"},
            {13,    "bssbbsbbbss"},
            {14,    "bssbbssbbbs"},
            {15,    "bsbbbssbbss"},
            {16,    "bssbbbsbbss"},
            {17,    "bssbbbssbbs"},
            {18,    "bbssbbbssbs"},
            {19,    "bbssbsbbbss"},
            {20,    "bbssbssbbbs"},
            {21,    "bbsbbbssbss"},
            {22,    "bbssbbbsbss"},
            {23,    "bbbsbbsbbbs"},
            {24,    "bbbsbssbbss"},
            {25,    "bbbssbsbbss"},
            {26,    "bbbssbssbbs"},
            {27,    "bbbsbbssbss"},
            {28,    "bbbssbbsbss"},
            {29,    "bbbssbbssbs"},
            {30,    "bbsbbsbbsss"},
            {31,    "bbsbbsssbbs"},
            {32,    "bbsssbbsbbs"},
            {33,    "bsbsssbbsss"},
            {34,    "bsssbsbbsss"},
            {35,    "bsssbsssbbs"},
            {36,    "bsbbsssbsss"},
            {37,    "bsssbbsbsss"},
            {38,    "bsssbbsssbs"},
            {39,    "bbsbsssbsss"},
            {40,    "bbsssbsbsss"},
            {41,    "bbsssbsssbs"},
            {42,    "bsbbsbbbsss"},
            {43,    "bsbbsssbbbs"},
            {44,    "bsssbbsbbbs"},
            {45,    "bsbbbsbbsss"},
            {46,    "bsbbbsssbbs"},
            {47,    "bsssbbbsbbs"},
            {48,    "bbbsbbbsbbs"},
            {49,    "bbsbsssbbbs"},
            {50,    "bbsssbsbbbs"},
            {51,    "bbsbbbsbsss"},
            {52,    "bbsbbbsssbs"},
            {53,    "bbsbbbsbbbs"},
            {54,    "bbbsbsbbsss"},
            {55,    "bbbsbsssbbs"},
            {56,    "bbbsssbsbbs"},
            {57,    "bbbsbbsbsss"},
            {58,    "bbbsbbsssbs"},
            {59,    "bbbsssbbsbs"},
            {60,    "bbbsbbbbsbs"},
            {61,    "bbssbssssbs"},
            {62,    "bbbbsssbsbs"},
            {63,    "bsbssbbssss"},
            {64,    "bsbssssbbss"},
            {65,    "bssbsbbssss"},
            {66,    "bssbssssbbs"},
            {67,    "bssssbsbbss"},
            {68,    "bssssbssbbs"},
            {69,    "bsbbssbssss"},
            {70,    "bsbbssssbss"},
            {71,    "bssbbsbssss"},
            {72,    "bssbbssssbs"},
            {73,    "bssssbbsbss"},
            {74,    "bssssbbssbs"},
            {75,    "bbssssbssbs"},
            {76,    "bbssbsbssss"},
            {77,    "bbbbsbbbsbs"},
            {78,    "bbssssbsbss"},
            {79,    "bsssbbbbsbs"},
            {80,    "bsbssbbbbss"},
            {81,    "bssbsbbbbss"},
            {82,    "bssbssbbbbs"},
            {83,    "bsbbbbssbss"},
            {84,    "bssbbbbsbss"},
            {85,    "bssbbbbssbs"},
            {86,    "bbbbsbssbss"},
            {87,    "bbbbssbsbss"},
            {88,    "bbbbssbssbs"},
            {89,    "bbsbbsbbbbs"},
            {90,    "bbsbbbbsbbs"},
            {91,    "bbbbsbbsbbs"},
            {92,    "bsbsbbbbsss"},
            {93,    "bsbsssbbbbs"},
            {94,    "bsssbsbbbbs"},
            {95,    "bsbbbbsbsss"},
            {96,    "bsbbbbsssbs"},
            {97,    "bbbbsbsbsss"},
            {98,    "bbbbsbsssbs"},
            {99,    "bsbbbsbbbbs"},
            {100,   "bsbbbbsbbbs"},
            {101,   "bbbsbsbbbbs"},
            {102,   "bbbbsbsbbbs"},
//          {103,   "bbsbsbbbbss"},
            {103,   "bbsbssssbss"},
            {104,   "bbsbssbssss"},
            {105,   "bbsbssbbbss"},
            {106,   "bbsssbbbsbsbb"},
        };  

        int i;
        IntString&inf=infs[iV];
        for(i=0;i<11;i++)
        {
            if(inf.psz[i]=='b') *pb+=1;
            pb++;
        }
        if(iV==106) 
        {
            *pb+=1; pb++;
            *pb+=1; pb++;
        }
        return pb;
    }

private:
    int GetCheckDigit(const int iSet,char*pszCode)
    {
        int iSum=0,iCurSet=0,iChar128,iCharNext,iWeight,iPosition;

        iCurSet=iSet;
        if(iSet==SUB::SETA)
        {
            iSum=103;
        }
        else 
        if(iSet==SUB::SETB)
        {
            iSum=104;
        }
        else 
        if(iSet==SUB::SETC)
        {
            iSum=105;
        }

        iPosition=0;
        iWeight=1;

        const int iNum=strlen(pszCode);
        while(iPosition<iNum)
        {
            if(iCurSet==SUB::SETC)
            {
                if(ga2_Code128[SUB::SETA][pszCode[iPosition]]==101)
                {
                    iChar128=101;
                    iSum+=(iWeight*iChar128);

                    iPosition++;
                    iWeight++;
                    iCurSet=SUB::SETA;
                }
                else if(ga2_Code128[SUB::SETA][pszCode[iPosition]]==100)
                {
                    iChar128=100;
                    iSum+=(iWeight*iChar128);
                    iPosition++;
                    iWeight++;
                    iCurSet=SUB::SETB;
                }
                else 
                if(ga2_Code128[SUB::SETA][pszCode[iPosition]]==102)
                {
                    iChar128=102;
                    iSum+=(iWeight*iChar128);
                    iPosition++;
                    iWeight++;
                }
                else
                {
                    char chT=pszCode[iPosition+2];
                    pszCode[iPosition+2]=0;
                    iChar128=atol(&pszCode[iPosition]);
                    pszCode[iPosition+2]=chT;

                    iSum +=(iWeight*iChar128);
                    iPosition +=2;
                    iWeight++;
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                int iTemp2=pszCode[iPosition];
                if(iTemp2<-1)   iTemp2=iTemp2&255;

                iChar128=ga2_Code128[iCurSet][iTemp2];

                iSum+=(iWeight*iChar128);

                iPosition++;
                iWeight++;

                if(iCurSet==SUB::SETA)
                {
                    if(iChar128==100)
                        iCurSet=SUB::SETB;
                    else if(iChar128==99)
                        iCurSet=SUB::SETC;
                }
                else 
                if(iCurSet==SUB::SETB)
                {
                    if(iChar128==101)       iCurSet=SUB::SETA;
                    else if(iChar128==99)   iCurSet=SUB::SETC;
                }
                else 
                if(iChar128==98)
                {
                    if(iCurSet==SUB::SETA)
                        iCharNext=ga2_Code128[SUB::SETB][pszCode[iPosition]];
                    else
                        iCharNext=ga2_Code128[SUB::SETA][pszCode[iPosition]];

                    iSum+=(iWeight*iCharNext);
                    iPosition++;
                    iWeight++;
                }
            }
        }
        return iSum%103;
    }
};


#endif
```

Программа запускается и завершается нормально, в конце написано Printed, то есть принтер был найден и ему были отосланы данные для печати, вроде))
Хотя при запуске в задачах принтера не появлялось ни одной задачи.
Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Отлаживайте DrawBarcode() и смотрите что API возвращают. Вполне возможно где-то не выходит получить объект через API и печать не происходит.